# Footer is not below as it is supposed to be. I need it to be below all other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, footer

The footer gets under the other elements and i want it to always be below them and it goes behind the images section.
i tried position:absolute;bottom:0 to the footer and position:relative and it did not work as i expected
here is the code link since its too long so i couldnt just type it here:
https://codepen.io/marwanoss/pen/gOmxPoP?editors=1100
(GUYS SOMEHOW IT WORKED WHEN I REMOVED THE FIXED HEIGHT FOR THE MAIN TAG , CAN ANYONE EXPLAIN HOW AND WHY DID IT WORK WHEN I REMOVED THE FIXED HEIGHT?)

```
<body>
<header>
    <div class="nav-container">
        <i class="fab fa-google-wallet"></i>
        <nav>
            <a href="">projects</a>
            <a href="">studio</a>
            <a href="">contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="header-content-container">
        <div class="header-content">
            <h1 class="adresses">
                tarryhill <br /> residence
            </h1>
            <p>austin / TX</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="header-background-radio">
            <li class="radio-dot radio-dot-1 is-selected">

            </li>
            <li class="radio-dot radio-dot-2">

            </li>
            <li class="radio-dot radio-dot-3">

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="gg-arrow-down"></i>
</header>
<main>
    <section class="about-us-section">
        <div class='about-us-info-wrapper'>
            <h2>about us</h2>
            <p>
                Founded in 2001, Andersson / Wise is focused on a collaborative approach to design that leads to a
                built
                solution attuned to its purpose, as well as the broader issues of image and context. Our design
                method
                begins by working closely with our client to understand the written and unwritten program and the
                complexities of the site.
            </p>
            <a href="" class="our-studio">
                <p>our studio</p>
                <svg class="arrow-right">
                    <use xlink:href="#arrow-right-long">
                        <symbol viewBox="0 0 31 15" fill="none" id="arrow-right-long"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <g clip-path="url(#dclip0)">
                                <path d="M0 7.5h30" stroke="currentColor"></path>
                                <path d="M24 1l6.5 6.5L24 14" stroke="currentColor"></path>
                            </g>
                            <defs>
                                <clipPath id="dclip0">
                                    <path fill="currentColor" d="M0 0h31v15H0z"></path>
                                </clipPath>
                            </defs>
                        </symbol>
                    </use>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: the code above is useless , just go to the link to see the complete code (html and css)

Comment: adding a useless code is useless. Add a minimal reproduciable code. Means that part of code that shows the issue. Dont write in Caps which is considered as shouting -> bad manners. Last but not least I can not see what your question has to do with JS.

Comment: @tacoshy Im sorry , i only added the code because stackoverflow commands it so i just picked a random chunk of code just to be able to post the question, next time ill try to pick a reproduciable chunk of code. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have a fixed height of 70rem on the main element, so your project section doesn't actually fit within the element and is overflowing, where as the footer is positioning relative to the 70rem element. just remove the fixed height and you're good to go.

Comment: To add to this, if you're still unsure about why this was happening, inspect the <main> element in the browser and you'll see that it is not large enough to contain its children.